# javafx charts,JavaFx - inference variable

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

I am using javafx charts in my project and
I want create some class get 2 type of date and return different charts in javafx.
I want to generic my code but get compile error!!
compiler :jdk 9.

superclas

```
public class ChartsModel <T,K> {

    private ObservableList<XYChart.Series<T,K>> list;
    protected    CategoryAxis xAxis;
    protected   NumberAxis yAxis;
    private void addnode(T name,K number)
    {
        XYChart.Series<T, K> series = new XYChart.Series<T, K>();
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<T, K>(name, number));
        list.add(series);
    }

    protected void  cheraxyAxis(String xAxisname, String yAxisname) {
        xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel(xAxisname);
        yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        yAxis.setLabel(yAxisname);
    }

    protected void addGroup(T[] name,K[] number,int conter){
        for (int i=0;i<conter;i++)
            addnode(name[i],number[i]);
    }

    public ObservableList<XYChart.Series<T, K>> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public CategoryAxis getxAxis() {
        return xAxis;
    }

    public NumberAxis getyAxis() {
        return yAxis;
    }


}
```

and this one of the my subclass:

```
public class Barcharts<T ,K > extends ChartsModel <T,K>
{
    private Barcharts() {}
    public BarChart<T,K> getBarchart(String xAxisname, String yAxisname,String Title,T[] name,K[] number,int conter)
    {
        cheraxyAxis(xAxisname,yAxisname);
        BarChart<T,K> barChart;

        barChart = new BarChart<>(xAxis,yAxis);
        //Error!!!

        barChart.setTitle(Title);
        addGroup(name,number,conter);
        barChart.setData(getList());
        return barChart;

    }
}
```

but when I use this line It work but not generic:

```
BarChart<String, Number> chart = new BarChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
```

Eror is:
Error:(13, 32) java: incompatible types: cannot infer type arguments for javafx.scene.chart.BarChart<>
    reason: inference variable X has incompatible equality constraints T,java.lang.String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `BarChart<X,Y>`n (or, generally, an `XYChart<X,Y>`) needs an `xAxis` of type `Axis<X>` and a `yAxis` of type `Axis<Y>`. You have defined `xAxis` to be a `CategoryAxis`, which is an `Axis<String>` and `yAxis` to be a `NumberAxis`, which is an `Axis<Number>`.

Consequently, the only type of `BarChart` you can create with those particular axes is a `BarChart<String, Number>`. The compiler is complaining because there is no constraint on your type variables `T` and `K` that would force them to be `String` and `Number`, respectively.

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do here. A `BarChart` **must** use one axis of type `String` and one of type `Number`. These can generally be in either order, but your code creates a vertical bar chart (by using the `CategoryAxis` as the x-axis). Consequently the data you use **must** be a `Series<String, Number>`, and so you must have `T` as `String` and `K` as `Number`; there's no choice on the types for the type variables, so there's really no point in making this generic at all.

Comment: thanks a lot. i change CategoryAxis to Axis<T> and NumberAxis to Axis<K> and it fix